# em dash followed by a comma

Tags: punctuation, commas, dashes

> I have three cars — blue, red, and green — , two motorcycles, and four bicycles.

Is this a correct use of comma after an em-dash? It seems quite weird. How should I use an em-dash and a comma here?

Comment: The second dash is not needed, maybe even incorrect.

Comment: @Kris I disagree. Dashes usually appear in pairs when setting off an aside like this. Without the second dash, there's no marker for the end of the side comment.

Comment: @BraddSzonye there is nothing parenthetical here.

Comment: The comma after the em dash is redundant. A semi-colon in place of the first em dash would be okay if the second em dash was also dropped. Either fix would work grammatically.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/121912/14666

Comment: The fact that the sentence enumerates three types of transportation means and introduces a parenthetical note for the colours of the first one (i.e. cars), seems to suggest to me that the comma should be kept. The reference pointed by @Kris refers to commas that "would ordinarily separate a dependent clause from an independent clause," not enumerations.

Answer (score -1):

See "*[D-a-s-h-e-s](http://www.menlo.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/D-a-s-h-e-s.pdf)*" [pdf 512kB]

> ***To prepare for a list, a restatement, an amplification, or a dramatic
>   shift in tone or thought***:
>
> - Along the wall are the bulk liquids—sesame oil, honey,
>     safflower oil, and that half-liquid, “peanuts only” peanut
>     butter.
> - In this last semester, Peter tried to pay more attention to his
>     priorities—applying to graduate school and getting financial
>     aid.
> - Everywhere we looked there were little kids—a box of Cracker
>     Jacks in one hand and mommy or daddy’s sleeve in the other.
> - Kiere took a few steps back, came running full speed, kicked a
>     mighty kick—and missed the ball.
>
> In the first 2 examples, the writer could also use a colon. The
>   colon is more formal than the dash and not quite as dramatic.

This is a case of both *list* and *amplification.* The phrase "blue, red, and green" lists and amplifies on "three cars."

Comment: This does not address the dash/comma combination at all, which is the crux of the question.

Comment: @BraddSzonye No need for haste. See also Stan's comment at OP. Your enthusiasm is appreciated, though.