# Is it acceptable to place a comma after the em-dash in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas, dashes, em-dashes

> Due to financial struggles brought on by marital struggles—or perhaps it was the other way around—, the family had to forsake it as the bank foreclosed on it.

I normally wouldn't place a comma, but had the statement between the dashes been missing like so—

> Due to financial struggles brought on by marital struggles,the family had to forsake it as the bank foreclosed on it.

...then there would be a comma.

Thanks for the help, lads and lasses.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9816/how-is-punctuation-used-after-dashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely do not need a comma in addition to the em dash because the em dash itself is a harder break than the comma would be. Think of the em dash as a comma on steroids; a comma produces a break, while an em dash produces a harder break.

Answer (score 0):

The sense of an introductory phrase is lost without the comma; however, a comma is simply wrong after an em dash.

I typically address this by using parentheses for nonessential information, thereby enabling the comma to be retained:

> Due to financial struggles brought on by marital struggles (or perhaps it was the other way around), the family had to forsake it as the bank foreclosed on it.